# Объясните почему разный результат я получил?

Tags: javascript

```js
function printNumbersInterval(){
  var i = 1;
  
  var d = setInterval(function(){
    console.log(i)
    if( i == 20 ){
      clearInterval(d)
    }
    i++
  }, 100)
}

printNumbersInterval()
```

```js
setInterval(function(){
  var i = 1
  console.log(i)
  i++
   console.log(i)
}, 100)
```

1. Я должен получить увеличение числа в 2 примере, но не получаю почему ?

Comment: `var i = 1` - вынесите это перед `setInterval(function(){` и будет увеличиваться.. У вас каждый раз сбрасывается переменная i до 1, отсюда и закономерный результат

Comment: Переменную i надо сделать глобальной. Вынесите её за пределы setInterval

Comment: @Владислав Жидко я правильно понял что setInterval каждый раз пересоздается поэтому число не увеличивается ?

Comment: @Leks, не совсем. Потому что в нём функция. Каждый раз, когда она вызывается, значение сбрасывается до исходного

Comment: @Владислав Жидко извините забыл написать спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setInterval вызывает переданную функцию с указанным интервалом.

Вы объявили локальную переменную внутри обработчика setInterval.
В каждой итерации - это новый вызов функции, а следовательно абсолютно новая переменная.

Для счётчика вам нужна область памяти(переменная) вне этой функции:

```js
{
  let i = 1; // Локальная переменная вне функции интервала
  setInterval(function(){
    console.log(i++);
  }, 700);
}
```

Comment: спасибо более менее стало понятно

Answer (score 1):

В первом случае происходит замыкание. Переменная `i` существует "где-то", остаётся доступной в анонимной функции, которая является аргументом для функции `setInterval`. Ваша функция, переданная в `setInterval` получает доступ к этой переменной `i`, выводит её на экран и инкрементирует (увеличивает на 1).

Во втором же случае нет никакой внешней переменной `i`. Переменная `i` инициализируется в теле самой функции. Каждый раз, когда вызывается функция - создаётся новая переменная `i`, выводится на экран, инкрементируется, снова выводится на экран. Каждый новый вызов функции никак не связан с предыдущим, переменная `i` всегда новая, следовательно, её значение не сохраняется.